# How to change color of ttk::combobox

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to change the color of a ttk::combobox widget. This is my code:

```
set MyBackgroundColor #00FF00
set MyForegroundColor #FF0000
font create MyFont -family Helvetica -size 12 -slant roman -weight normal
ttk::style theme use default
ttk::style configure TCombobox -font MyFont -background $MyBackgroundColor -fieldbackground $MyBackgroundColor -foreground $MyForegroundColor
option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.font MyFont
option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.background $MyBackgroundColor
option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.foreground $MyForegroundColor
# option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.selectbackground $MyBackgroundColor
# option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.selectforeground $MyForegroundColor

set Liste {Anton Berta Caesar}
set MyVar [lindex $Liste 0]
ttk::combobox .cb -values $Liste -textvariable MyVar -font MyFont -background $MyBackgroundColor -foreground $MyForegroundColor
pack .cb
```

If I open up the combobox and move the mouse over the entries, the entries are higlighted with black font color and grey background color. Is it possible to change these colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the popdown colors with the following options:

```
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.background color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.foreground color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground color
option add *TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground color
```

Edit:

If you need to change a particular popdown's colors or change the 
colors after the combobox is created:

```
set popdown [ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow .combo]
$popdown.f.l configure -background color
```

References: [wiki: Changing Widget Colors](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors#8a4d72b63cef31a5b7a21aa955274f4fe4e04ff0ab1fe2578400782876dc183f)

Comment: This works if the state of the combobox is not readonly. So I added `ttk::style map TCombobox state {}`. Is this correct? Another problem occurs when the combox widget is a children of a frame widget. Then the background color is grey again.

Comment: I changed the `ttk::style map` command into `ttk::style map TCombobox -background [list disabled color readonly color]` and `ttk::style map TCombobox -fieldbackground [list disabled color readonly color]` and it works fine. It solved problem with the parent frame widget too.

Comment: It appears that the listbox background colors have to be set before the combobox is instantiated.  Do you need to change them dynamically?